# Excel Filter VB Macro for 2 Different Columns

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I have 2 columns that will either be blank, or display which database a user has access to. The columns are not identical, so there needs to be OR logic in the macro, but I can't get the syntax right. Here's what I have- the toggling works great, just can't get the OR. I would really prefer to get this method working, and not the "Advanced Filter" method.

```
With ActiveSheet
    If .AutoFilterMode = True And .FilterMode = True Then
        .AutoFilterMode = False And .FilterMode = False
    Else
        .AutoFilterMode = True And .FilterMode = True
        ActiveSheet.Range("$E$7:$P$1765").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=DatabaseA", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Field:=7, Criteria2:="=DatabaseA"
    End If
End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided the best solution is to just make the 2 columns output to a 3rd column:

```
=IF(K8="DatabaseA","DatabaseA",IF(Q8="DatabaseA","DatabaseA","--"))
```

and the new columns inputs into the macro. Works great.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code I get this

[image]

So it appears to do as expected creating an OR.
I would check that your definition of DatabaseA is being set as expected.
If you intended the string "DatabaseA" as a filter criteria you might drop the preceding equal sign, or is DatabaseA a variable?
It isn't clear from your example which is the case